# Resource instead of external file C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, file-io, embedded-resource

I am reusing some old code(originally developed on c, not c++) with some functions to open/read/manipulate text-files. The path to the text-files is passed to the functions as a string (char*) then opened using: `FileToUse = fopen(filename, "rb");` then multiple calls to `fread()` and `fseek()` are used. This code is known to work for external text-files, but now I would like to include the textfiles as resources in my project (MFC C++ in visual studio).

I found some examples on the web on how to use resources rusulting in this code:

```
HINSTANCE hInst = AfxGetResourceHandle();
HRSRC hResource = FindResource(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_TEXTFILE1), "TEXTFILE");

if (hResource){
  HGLOBAL hLoadedResource = LoadResource(hInst, hResource);
  if (hLoadedResource){
    const char* pResource = LockResource(hLoadedResource);
    if (pResource){
      DWORD dwResourceSize = SizeofResource(hInst, hResource);
      if (0 != dwResourceSize){                            // if(FileToUse){
        memcpy(&Buffer, pResource, (15 * 2));              //   fread($Buffer, 15, 2, FileToUse);
        pTemp = pResource + 200;                           //   fseek(FileToUse, 200, SEEK_SET);
        pTemp = pTemp + 100;                               //   fseek(FileToUse, 100, SEEK_CUR);
        pTemp = pResource + (dwResourceSize - 1) - 40;     //   fseek(FileToUse, -40, SEEK_END);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I replaced the fread call by memcpy() as shown, but I'm missing the return value of fread (actual read items) and in the original code the filepointer was moved by fseek, I wonder whether my approach using a temporary pointer is correct.

My ultimate goal is to simulate the fread and fseek calls for resources with similar function prototypes:

`size_t resread( void* buffer, size_t size, size_t count, char* resource );`

`int resseek( char* resource, long offset, int origin );`

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: This question seems to be entirely windows specific. You should consider adding such a tag.

Comment: @bjhend The code behind loading resources is windows-specific, but he already got that right. Question is about duplicating fread so it's platform agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help, based on the Agent_L's suggestion this is what I came up with:

Text-resource type:

```
struct _resource {
    const char * content;      // File content
    size_t size;               // File size
    size_t ptrloc;             // 'Pointer' location
};
typedef struct _resource RES_TXT;
```

resread based on fread:

```
size_t resread( void* buffer, size_t size, size_t count, RES_TXT * resource)
{
    size_t actualCount = ( resource->size - resource->ptrloc ) / size;
    actualCount = min( count, actualCount );
    if ( actualCount <= 0 ) return 0;
    memcpy(buffer, (resource->_ptr + resource->ptrloc), (actualCount * size) );
    resource->ptrloc += (actualCount * size);
    return actualCount;
}
```

and to complete resseek based on fseek:

```
int resseek( RES_TXT * resource, long offset, int origin ) {
    size_t nextloc;
    switch ( origin ) {
        case SEEK_SET: nextloc = 0;
            break;
        case SEEK_CUR: nextloc = resource->ptrloc;
            break;
        case SEEK_END: nextloc = resource->size;
            break;
        default: return -1;
    }
    nextloc += offset;
    if ( nextloc >= 0  && nextloc < resource->size )
        resource->ptrloc = nextloc;
    else
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Any call to fseek and fread can now be replaced to use a resource instead of an external file.

Answer (score 1):

The file handle contains not only the data but also it's length and current position. You have to duplicate that.
(handwirtten code, unproven):

```
struct resFile
{
    char* pData;
    int iLenght;
    int iCurrPosition;
};

size_t resread( void* buffer, size_t size, size_t count, resFile* resource)
{
    int ActualRead = min(size*count, resource->iLenght - resource->iCurrPosition);
    memcpy(buffer, resource->pData + resource->iCurrPosition, ActualRead);
    resource->iCurrPostion += ActualRead;
    return ActualRead;
}
```

Comment: Good point, this also means that it might be possible to put the data pointer of the resource in data member of standard FILE (_iobuf) struct. I would have to determine the other members for the resource though. I'll look into the exact struct members and their functions.

Comment: Oh, do not mess with that. FILE has an actual file name and an open file handle, and Bill knows what's happening inside actual fread.
Reimplementing fread and fseek is really easy.
In C++ you can overload fopen, fread and fseek, so only changing FILE to resFile would be required. Or perhaps you could even get away with #define FILE resFile.

Comment: I noticed that the return value for fread is not the bytecount but the number of actual blocks read (of bytecount 'size') see my accepted answer for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Let me notify you that `fread` shifts current file position. This means that you don't need invoke `fseek` each time. From this perspective **may** be you code can avoid implementation of `resseek` by simple increasing `Buffer` pointer

Comment: I was aware of the fact that the filepointer is shifted by fread however the fseek is for example also used as check: if(fseek(FileToUse, (next position calculation), 0) == -1) return ERROR;